# How to determine an injectable angular service at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular

I apologize in advance for not creating a plunker for this code, there is a number of third party controls that are needed for it to run.

My question is about selecting service, dependency injection, at run time, based on some conditions.

lets discuss only one service for this example.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
    constructor (
        private http: Http) {
    }
}
```

In my component if I have a fixed one, all is well.

```
import {Component, ViewChild, OnChanges, Input, ReflectiveInjector, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Service1 } from './my.service.1';
@Component({
    providers: [
        Service1
    ],
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private service : Service1
        ) {
}
```

in the above case all is well, no runtime errors.

Now if I change to the dynamic version, I get an error 
EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.html:5:8 caused by: No provider for Http! (Service1 -> Http)

the version of code causing the error is:

I added a member variable for MyComponent: private service: any = '';

and the constructor now looks like

```
constructor() {

    // this does not work with the http module
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Service1]);
    this.service = injector.get(Service1);
}
```

anyone sees what is causing the above mentioned error?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add Http to the array passed in   `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate` :

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Service1,Http]);
```

Comment: No change after I added your recommendation.

Comment: sorry, I just looked for you , its difficult because Http has its own dependencies  and these depenendes have their dependencies so you have to provide all these dependecies to the `ReflectiveInjector` in order to get your `Service1`. take a look here https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js